# Custom horizontal pop transition not working as it should

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to create a custom horizontal slide UINavigationController transition. And the push animation seems to work fine. But when I'm trying to pop (and have that horizontal slide back) where's only a blank screen and after animation time the view appears where it should

```
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let container = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from)!
        let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to)!

        let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransform(translationX: container.frame.width, y: 0)
        let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -container.frame.width, y: 0)

        fromView.frame = transitionContext.initialFrame(for: transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!)
        toView.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)!)

        toView.transform = isPresenting == true ? offScreenRight : offScreenLeft



        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(fromView)

        let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

            fromView.transform = self.isPresenting == true ? offScreenLeft : offScreenRight
            toView.transform = .identity

        }, completion: { finished in

            toView.frame = transitionContext.initialFrame(for: transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)!)
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to reset any existing transforms on your views.

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let container = transitionContext.containerView
    let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from)!
    let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to)!

    // add these two lines      
    fromView.transform = .identity
    toView.transform = .identity

    // ... the rest of your existing code
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That did it! Thanks! I thought those views are clean from transform from the beginning, heh :)